# Flash messages messes up flexbox layout

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app where I use flexbox to separate the header, content, and footer. This flexbox ensures that the content is filled with whitespace to fill the entire screen, making the footer to always be at the bottom of the layout just as shown in the image.

[image]

(Don't mind the bad layout will eventually improve it)

The code I used to do this are the following:

```
# application.html.slim
  body
    .box
      .row.header
        = render 'layouts/navbar'
      .row.content
        = yield
      .row.footer
        = render 'layouts/footer'
```

```
# custom.css.scss
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

It works as expected. However, when I started the login functionality of devise and trigger error/success messages, the layout gets messed up and now looks like:

[image]

When I used inspect element, I saw that the `<div class="row footer">` disappears and the `= render 'layouts/footer'` becomes under `<div class="row content">`

I am not quite sure what triggers this behavior and I've got no luck finding it so far.

My template for flash is:

```
# _flash.html.erb

- if !flash.empty?
  .row
    - flash.each do |message_type, message|
      |  <div class="
      = flash_class(message_type)
      |  closable"> 
      i.close.icon
      = message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to close the flash custom div:

```rb
  .row
    - flash.each do |message_type, message|
      |  <div class="
      = flash_class(message_type)
      |  closable"> 
      i.close.icon
      = message
      |  </div> #<= here
```

Comment: Yikes can't believe I missed that simple closing tag! Got used to slim automatically adding the closing tags. Thanks for pointing that one out!